# Execution time between Angular and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a page that's dynamically populated through Angular. Essentially, Angular makes an `$http.get` request to the backend to get the data and populates attributes of a controller.

For instance, I call `$http.get('/_car_data')` and the JSON that is returned is saved into my controller `Dealership` as `Dealership.cars`.

Through Angular, I then output all the `Dealership.cars` as input boxes in my html page.

My problem is that I want to add a jquery 'autocomplete' to each input. This works beautifully if I do it through the Google Developer console after the page and angular has entirely rendered. However, if I include this functionality both after the script is linked to the html and after the body of the html, it does not work. It also does not work if I surround this autocomplete functionality with `$( document ).ready`.

This is the function that works perfectly when run in the google developer console but not from including it after the externally linked js and the html body.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        var availableTags = [];

        $.ajax({
              url: '_available_cars',
              data: {},
              method: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                  availableCars = data['cars'];

                  $( ".carchoice" ).autocomplete({
                       source: availableCars
                   });
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
                  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
              }
         });
});
```

So my question is, how do I wait until all html and Angular-created, dynamically-loaded content finishes rendering to execute my jquery statement?

Comment: You must do it in the angularjs way. That is, with directives.

Comment: Question and thinking is wrong. You need to call the plugin in a directive. Then you are assured the element exists

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `link` function [Agular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom). This function is triggered when html template for your component is compiled and you have Element still not linked to real DOM. So you can try to manipulate this element with jQuery autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The best and unique way that jQuery should comunicate with angularjs is through directives. I recommend you to avoid any kind of shortcut and hacks, it turns into the real chaos with just a little bit of code.

Here is my sugestion of how your problem can be solved.

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').factory('CarService', function ($http, $q) {
    var cars = [];

    return {
        getAvailableCars: function () {
            if(cars) return $q.resolve(cars);

            return $http.get('_available_cars').then(function (response) {

                cars = response.data;

                return cars;
            });
        }
    };
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('carchoice', function(CarService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            CarService
                .getAvailableCars()
                .then(function (availableCars) {

                    $(element).autocomplete({
                        source: availableCars
                    });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: not a big deal but FYI `element` is already jQuery if jQuery.js included in page before angular.js

Comment: The reason for me to let `element` wrapped by jquery's function is because it's more general and clear about what is happening in the code. Even though element could already be wrapped by jQuery, it woudn't cause any problem, right? Cause jQuery handles it in his internals. But, thank you anyways for pointing us a good fact that normally we wouldn't notice.

Comment: no not a problem and some people may not include it before angular.js. It would be same as `$($(selector))` which does work. But when all configured properly can just do `element.pluginName()`